# I need to show 2 decimal place in one column in hive sql

Tags: sql, hive

I need to show up the value to 2 decimal places.

*Column_value = 6.567878*

If i use round off to above values,

```
round(Column_value,2)
```

the result will be **6.57**...
Expecte output will be **6.56**...

Comment: do you want 6.57 or 6.58?

Comment: @KoushikRoy-Neither...Output expected was 6.56

Answer (score 0):

But when you rounding above 5 and higher after 2 digits you have default rounding as you wrote to higher value as **6.57**. Ceiling function gives you chance to round down but only as integer without decimal places.

Comment: i dont need to round up or round down.I need to show only 2 decimal places...